# 'This' is undefined in es6 class method even if it is defined

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

`this` is not available in the methods. More details in my code (comment blocks) about what is available, it's difficult to explain this in plain text. This is probably a duplicate but I don't find a straight answer anywhere.

Is something wrong with this code, or is there a logic workaround?

#### Class

```
class CheckParameters {  
    get parameters() {
        return this._parameters;
    }                                                                                                     
    constructor(parameters) {                                                                                                 
        this._parameters = parameters;                                                                                        
        console.log(this);   //this is defined                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                              
    CheckQueryParam (req, res, next) {  
        console.log(this);   // undefined                                                                                      
        let parameterChecks = this._parameters.map(param => { // TypeError: Cannot read property '_parameters' of undefined   
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...});                                                                   
        });                                                                                                                   
        Promise.all(parameterChecks)                                                                                          
            .then(() => next())                                                                                               
            .catch((error) => {                                                                                               
                console.error(error);                                                                                         
                res.status(400).send(error)                                                                                   
            });                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                         
}
```

#### Using the class

```
console.log(LimitAndOffset.parameters); //Also this is defined

const LimitAndOffset = new CheckParameters([ 
    new Parameter(    //Parameter is another class, this works perfectly                       
        "limit",                             
        Number,                              
        [Validators.Number],                 
        true                                 
    ),                                       
    new Parameter(                           
        "offset",                            
        Number,                              
        [Validators.Number],                 
        true                                 
    )                                        
]);  

app.get('/', LimitAndOffset.CheckQueryParam, function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json('piemel');
});
```

Comment: When you pass `LimitAndOffset.CheckQueryParam` as a value, you lose the relationship to the object. The value of `this` depends on how a function is **called**, not on how it's defined.

Comment: Sounds fair, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: use `.bind(this)`.

Comment: In the constructor you'll want to bind your function to this.

`constructor() { this.CheckQueryParam = this.CheckQueryParam.bind(this); }`

Comment: You guys just made my day!